# How do I swap the nodes of a linked list in a bubble-sort algorithm?

Tags: c, sorting, swap, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort

In C I have to write a bubble sort function that **swaps the nodes and not the values** of a LinkedList, but I'm unable to accomplish it. Here is the code (As you can see the order is not correct):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h> // malloc, free
#include <stddef.h> // NULL

// defining 'int' as data_t
typedef int data_t;

typedef struct node_s {
    data_t data;
    struct node_s* next;
} node_t;

node_t** list_new() {
    node_t** list = malloc(sizeof **list);
    if (!list) return NULL;
    *list = NULL;
    return list;
}

void list_delete(node_t** list) {
    node_t *node, *next;
    for (node = *list; node; node = next) {
        next = node->next;
        free(node);
    }
}

node_t* list_push_front(node_t** list, data_t data) {
    node_t* node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (!node) return NULL;
    node->data = data;
    node->next = *list;
    return *list = node;
}

// IS EASY TO SWAP THE VALUES
/*
void swap(data_t* a, data_t* b) {
    data_t c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}

void simple_bubble_sort(node_t** list) {
    for(node_t* i = *list; i; i = i->next)
        for(node_t* j = *list; j->next; j = j->next)
            if(j->data > j->next->data)
                swap(&(j->data), &(j->next->data));

}
*/
// MUCH LESS EASY TO SWAP THE NODES
void swap_node(node_t** prev_node_A, node_t** node_A, node_t** node_B) {
        node_t *last_node = (*node_B)->next;
        node_t *first_node = *node_A;
        node_t *second_node = *node_B;
        if (prev_node_A) {
            (*prev_node_A)->next = second_node;
            (*prev_node_A)->next->next = first_node;
            (*prev_node_A)->next->next->next = last_node;
        } else {
            (*node_A) = second_node;
            (*node_A)->next = first_node;
            (*node_A)->next->next = last_node;
        }
}

void simple_bubble_sort(node_t** list) {

    for(node_t* i = *list; i->next; i = i->next)
        for (node_t *j = *list; j->next->next; j = j->next) {
            if (j == *list) {
                if (j->data > j->next->data) {
                    *list = j->next;
                    swap_node(NULL, &j, &(j->next));
                }
            }
            else {
                if (j->next->data > j->next->next->data)
                    swap_node(&j, &(j->next), &(j->next->next));
            }
            //printf("%i,%i | %i, %i, %i, %i \n", i->data, j->data, (*list)->data, (*list)->next->data, (*list)->next->next->data, (*list)->next->next->next->data);
            //system("pause");
        }
}


int main() {
    // Create List
    node_t** list = list_new();
    if (!list)
        goto memory_allocation_failure;

    // Add values to List
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        if (!list_push_front(list, i))
            goto memory_allocation_failure;

    // Print List
    for (node_t* node = *list; node != NULL; node = node->next)
        printf("%i\n", node->data);

    // Swap Test
    //swap_node(NULL, &(*list), &((*list)->next));
    //swap_node(&(*list), &((*list)->next), &((*list)->next->next));

    // Sort List
    printf("-- Bubble Sort --\n");
    simple_bubble_sort(list);

    // Print List
    for (node_t* node = *list; node != NULL; node = node->next)
        printf("%i\n", node->data);

    // Delete List
    list_delete(list);
    return 0;

    // Error Handler
    memory_allocation_failure:
        printf("Memory Allocation Failure");
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I meant it as a joke based on how the question was phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function `swap`.

```
 void swap( node_t **current )  
 {  
     node_t *tmp = ( *current )->next->next;  

     ( *current )->next->next = *current;  


     *current = ( *current )->next;  

     ( *current )->next->next = tmp;  
 }
```

And here is the function `simple_bubble_sort`

```
 void simple_bubble_sort( node_t **head )  
 {  
     if ( *head )  
     {  
         for ( node_t **first = head, *sorted = NULL, *last = sorted;  
               ( *first )->next != last;  
               last = sorted )  
         {  
             sorted = ( *first )->next; 
             for ( node_t **current = first; ( *current )->next != last; current = &( *current )->next )  
             {  
                 if ( ( *current )->next->data < ( *current )->data )  
                 {  
                     swap( current );  

                     sorted = ( *current )->next;  
                 }  
             }  
         }  
     }  
 }
```

Investigate them.

Pay attention to that the header `<malloc.h>` is not a standard C header. Instead use the header `<stdlib.h>`.

You need to revise your current code. For example this function

```
node_t** list_new() {
    node_t** list = malloc(sizeof **list);
    if (!list) return NULL;
    *list = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

does not make sense it should be removed.

What you need is just to define in main a pointer like

```
node_t *head = NULL;
```

And pass it to functions as for example to the function `simple_bubble_sort` like

```
simple_bubble_sort( &head );
```

Or the function `list_push_front`  should be defined like

```
int list_push_front(node_t** list, data_t data) 
{
    node_t* node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = *list;
        *list = node;
    }

    return success;;
}
```

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to have header `swap( node_t *current)` and call by reference `swap(&current)` and change accordingly the code inside?

Comment: @Katsu I have not understood what you are asking. I showed the function  swap. What is the problem?

Comment: I just try to understand pointer to pointer and see when it's necessary or not to use it and if I can avoid it by using reference instead.

Comment: @Katsu In C there are no references. Pass by reference in C means passing pointer to an object.  If the object is itself a pointer then you have to pass pointer to pointer.

Comment: [ok thanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference)